# Кто-нибудь. Для чего конкретно нужна инкапсуляция? Какой в ней смысл? Можно ли без нее?

Tags: python, c#, c++, ооп, инкапсуляция

Зачем вообще делать атрибуты в классах закрытыми(приватными), какой в этом смысл? Наверно, без конкретного хорошего примера в программе это понять трудно для чего инкапсуляция. Ну создали мы атрибуты и что дальше? Какие вообще переменные стоит закрывать, и какой в этом смысл? Не хотят вызывать они эти 'приватные' методы, так не вызывайте, только какой смысл их закрывать, разве что эти подчеркивания только для формальности(будто это электрическая или механическая начинка и пользователю это знать не нужно(ссылаюсь пример с кофемолкой)), но ведь пользователь не производитель(разработчик, программист), его это не касается и оно его и так не коснется. Без хорошего примера, может, в каком-нибудь проекте или в программе полезность инкапсуляции понять сложновато.

Пусть каждый, читающий этот вопрос, напишет свое мнение и как он это понимает. Спасибо.

Comment: Пользователь вполне может оказаться производителем.

Comment: *"НАПИШЕТ СВОЕ МНЕНИЕ"* - писать капсом некультурно, вопросы и ответы про мнения являются офтопиком

Comment: Что-то не так??

Comment: @user463261 в первую очередь не так то, что вы не читали теорию или нерешали задач по ООП. Иначе бы этот вопрос не возник. В худшем случае на разбор вопроса нужен час времени максимум, половину из которого вы уже потратили на работу с этим вопросом. Материалов для изучения полинтернета, выбирайте любую статью для любого языка.

Comment: Ну соответственно вопросы возникают когда теория не очень понятна. И что, вопрос нельзя задать. Извините что написал этот вопрос и отнял у вас несколько минут гуру программирования

Comment: @user463261 ваш вопрос чисто теоретический, а теги стоят по языкам программирования. Но в разных языках разные подходы к инкапсуляции. Следовательно и пример не написать. Вон вам ниже написали ответы, каждый из них по-своему хорош.

Comment: Если пишете один (или в вашей компании каждый пишет свои модули и никто не трогает чужой код), то можно и без private. По большому счету, инкапсуляция -- это попытка улучшить управление сопровождением кода в больших коллективах. И вам ее навязывают в предположении, что когда-нибудь вы можете попасть на такой конвейер и для всех будет лучше, если вы уже впитали эти принципы коллективизма (но в современном толерантном мире о таком предпочитают умалчивать)

Comment: @avp В случае с живым человеком, который обладает свойством наглухо забывать о том, что он там писал полгода назад, разработчик, даже работая в одну каску, становится таким *коллективом*- относительно самого себя полугодичной давности. Собственно, по этой причине, средства, якобы нужные только при командной разработке, как то - система управления версиями и багтрекер нужны и инди-разработчикам в том числе.

Comment: @gbg, а особенно нужны ТЗ (прямо в каком-нибудь из read.me), актуальные комментарии и инструкция по запуску тестовых наборов

Comment: Вот ещё по теме: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/639016/10105

Comment: Вот устроитесь вы на работу, попадёте на поддержку крупного проекта, в котором миллионы строк кода без инкапсуляции. И все они вам доступны! Вот радость-то! Разбирайтесь... А с инкапсуляцией вам будет доступна гораздо меньшая часть - только нужное.

Answer (score 5):

Предствьте, что в вашем рабочем столе есть ящик с докуметом. К вам подходят люди и просят вас туда что-то записать. У вас есть свой подход к хранению, и добавлению записей. Кроме того вы иногда достаете этот документ оттуда и расчитываете что записи в нем будут вам понятны, потмоу что вы их сами туда занесли.

И тут кто-то в обход вас берет и не учитывая ваш подход вносит изменение. Когда вы снова туда залезете это как минимум поставит вас в тупик а как максимум приветет к краху всей организации.

Вы - это методы объекта. Пока поле (ящик) было икапсулировано, риск того что состояние объекта придет в неожиданное вами состояние отсутвтсует. Как только поле стало открытым всем появился риск создания неконсистентного состояния (например изменение одних полей должны соотв-но влиять на другие)

Answer (score 2):

Полезность хорошей инкапсуляции (в паблик смотрят только методы) состоит в том, что в программе уменьшается связность между классами.

Это позволяет с меньшей вероятностью появления ошибок править конкретные классы, не трогая остальные.

*Пользователи класса* (в данном случае, это программисты, которые вызывают методы) при таком подходе меньше рискуют получить WTF-эффект - неинтуитивное поведение класса после того, как ему поменяют поля извне.